# Warning initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast with fgets

Tags: c, casting, warnings, fgets

I want want to read a character string, over the stdin, so I have chosen fgets. But I got this warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define MAX_LINIA 301

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char *buffer;
    printf("Enter the input\n");
    if (fgets(buffer,MAX_LINIA-1,stdin)==NULL) printf("Error")
    else printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0:
}
```

Comment: `buffer` is uninitialized. It's *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: The code should not emit the warning you cite above. Please show the real code you use

Comment: first, `printf("Error")` --> `printf("Error");` and `return 0:` --> `return 0;`

Comment: Using an uninitialised variable _in general_ is not undefined behaviour. But you dereference an indeterminate address. That's something different!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `buffer` without initialising it, which causes undefined behaviour.

You don't need to use pointer, and can use char array instead (given the max size already defined):

```
char buffer[MAX_LINIA];
```

The fgets then be better written as:

```
if(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)==NULL)
```

Comment: That's not exactly correct. Accessing the pointer is not UB in C, but dereferencing it's value is.